# React Native Create Ellipsis Clipped Text in React Native iOS Android or How to make extra text hidden with dots in React native

Tags: javascript, html, react-native, frontend, ellipsis

```
<Text style={styles.TextStyle}> 
  This is the Sample Ellipsis Text for Ellipsis from Start.This is the Sample Ellipsis Text for Ellipsis from Start.This is the Sample Ellipsis Text for Ellipsis from Start.
</Text>
```

I want to use dots if content exceed more than what I need to display

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reference for the answer [numberOfLines](https://reactnativecode.com/text-overflow-create-ellipsis-text/).
just use numberOfLines quantity, if you put numberOfLines = { 2 }, it will display 2 lines and extra text will be in dots.

```
<Text style={styles.TextStyle} numberOfLines = { 1 } ellipsizeMode = 'head'> 
  This is the Sample Ellipsis Text for Ellipsis from Start.This is the Sample Ellipsis Text for Ellipsis from Start.This is the Sample Ellipsis Text for Ellipsis from Start.
</Text>
```